# Jersey client file upload exception: NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/HeadersFactory

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey

im trying to create a jersey client to upload files. I`ve searched the i-net but i cant find a proper solution for my exception.

This is my client code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

//...

private static void clientUploadTest() {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    Client client       = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
    client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    URI baseUri         = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/rest/test").build();
    WebTarget target    = client.target(baseUri);

    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();

}
```

If i try to add the multiPart, i got the following exception. I tried different ways but i fix my problem. i also tried something like this:

```
final FileDataBodyPart filepart     = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/testtext.txt"));
FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
final FormDataMultiPart multiPart   = (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart.field("foo", "bar").bodyPart(filepart);
```

but i got the same error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/HeadersFactory
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.BodyPart.<init>(BodyPart.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart.<init>(MultiPart.java:66)
    at de.restclient.requests.ClientTest.clUploadtest(ClientTest.java:64)
    at de.restclient.requests.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeadersFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more`

And this are my imported jersey files.

[Jersey files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2L83.jpg)

Im able to send normal GET and Post Request to the server. But i need to send files too. 
I hope, someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're [missing a dependency](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-multipart/):

```
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart
```

Comment: Thx, for the fast answer. I have added the newest jersey-media-multipart.jar and now there is no error. Thx for the hint. I had the jersey-media-multipart-2.0-m11 but i think, it wasn't the newest.

Comment: You should match the version with the ones that you already have.